# Rails + Devise: Sharing session variables across subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, subdomain

I've read a bunch of SO questions regarding sharing session variables across subdomains but I cannot seem to get it working.  I currently have the following an initializer for **2 different apps**.

```
# App 1: hosted at new.domain_name.com
if Rails.env.development?
    Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_app_session'
else
    Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_app_session', domain: "domain_name.com"
end

# App 2: hosted at www.domain_name.com
if Rails.env.development?
    Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_app_session'
else
    Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_app_session', domain: "domain_name.com"
end
```

Is this how you set it up, where `domain_name.com` is the specified domain in your config file?

When I sign in in one app, the other app is unaware.  Does the fact that they are 2 different apps have anything to do with it?  Will I need to change anything so the token is decryptable?

Comment: We are using same session between two apps. Here is the our session_store.rb Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_ourapp_#{Rails.env}", domain: :all, tld_length: 2

Comment: @Muhammet how to you access a user from the value that gets saved to the `session_store`.  My value does not give me any information other than the `session_id`

Comment: We use devise gem. So current_user is returning the logged in user.

Comment: and you can use `current_user` across the domains?  Mine is not recognizing there is a `current_user` and I thought I could use this `session_id` to track it

Comment: Can you try to do it with my configuration in session_store.rb ?